# Is this combinatorics derivation correct?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, generating-functions, stirling-numbers

On the Wikipedia I found the following formula:

$ x^m = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m+1} \left \{ \begin{array}{cols} m+1 \\ k \end{array}\right \} (x-1)^{\underline{k-1}} \,\,\,\,\,\, (1) $

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Generating_functions

Now on [another forum](https://www.wetenschapsforum.nl/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=211872) the question was asked if the formula below is correct:

$ x^m = \sum\limits_{i=0}^m \left ( \begin{array}{cols} x-1 \\ i \end{array}\right ) \cdot \sum\limits_{j=0}^i \left ( \begin{array}{cols} i \\ j \end{array}\right ) (-1)^j (i+1-j)^m \,\,\,\,\,\, (2) $

After much trouble I may have found a derivation of formula (2) from formula (1). But I'm only an amateur, and I would like to hear from some experts whether or not my derivation is correct.

This is my derivation:

$ x^m = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m+1} \left \{ \begin{array}{cols} m+1 \\ k \end{array}\right \} (x-1)^{\underline{k-1}} $

[Change of dummy variable]

$ x^m = \sum\limits_{i=0}^m (x-1)^{\underline{i}} \cdot \left \{ \begin{array}{cols} m+1 \\ i+1 \end{array}\right \} $

[Definition of Stirling numbers of the second kind.]

$ x^m = \sum\limits_{i=0}^m (x-1)^{\underline{i}} \cdot \frac{1}{(i+1)!} \sum\limits_{j=0}^{i+1} (-1)^j \left ( \begin{array}{cols} i+1 \\ j \end{array}\right ) (i+1-j)^{m+1} $

[Term for j=i+1 is zero.]

$ x^m = \sum\limits_{i=0}^m (x-1)^{\underline{i}} \cdot \frac{1}{(i+1)!} \sum\limits_{j=0}^i (-1)^j \left ( \begin{array}{cols} i+1 \\ j \end{array}\right ) (i+1-j)^{m+1} $

[(i+1)! = i!.(i+1)]

$ x^m = \sum\limits_{i=0}^m \frac{(x-1)^{\underline{i}}}{ i! } \cdot \frac{1}{i+1} \sum\limits_{j=0}^i (-1)^j \left ( \begin{array}{cols} i+1 \\ j \end{array}\right ) (i+1-j)^{m+1} $

[Identity for the binomial coefficient.]

$ x^m = \sum\limits_{i=0}^m \left ( \begin{array}{cols} x-1 \\ i \end{array}\right ) \cdot \frac{1}{i+1} \sum\limits_{j=0}^i (-1)^j \left ( \begin{array}{cols} i+1 \\ j \end{array}\right ) (i+1-j)^{m+1} $

[(i+1-j)^(m+1) = (i+1-j).(i+1-j)^m.]

$ x^m = \sum\limits_{i=0}^m \left ( \begin{array}{cols} x-1 \\ i \end{array}\right ) \cdot \sum\limits_{j=0}^i \left ( \begin{array}{cols} i+1 \\ j \end{array}\right ) \frac{i+1-j}{i+1} \, (-1)^j (i+1-j)^m $

[Identity for the binomial coefficient.]

$ x^m = \sum\limits_{i=0}^m \left ( \begin{array}{cols} x-1 \\ i \end{array}\right ) \cdot \sum\limits_{j=0}^i \left ( \begin{array}{cols} i \\ j \end{array}\right ) (-1)^j (i+1-j)^m $

Comment: It would be **much** appreciated if you give justification for each step in your question.

Comment: Thank you! I have now added brief explanations to the steps of de derivation.

Comment: All those steps look correct to me.

Comment: Thank you very much for checking the derivation!